# How to configure Sensu with RMQ and InfluxDB

Tags: rabbitmq, influxdb, sensu

I am trying to get started with a monitoring server solution. I got the Sensu Clients, RabbitMQ and Uchiwa configured but then I tried using Graphite but there were so many parts to configure I tried InfluxDB instead. I am stuck configuring Sensu to InfluxDB. 
Is there a part missing in the below configuration?

```
Client [Sensu] > RabbitMQ <> Sensu Server <> InfluxDB <> Grafana
```

Any suggestions?

```
cat influx.json
{
    "influxdb": {
    "hosts"         : ["192.168.1.1"],
    "host"          : "192.168.1.1",
    "port"          : "8086",
    "database"      : "sensumetrics",
    "time_precision": "s",
    "use_ssl"       : false,
    "verify_ssl"    : false,
    "initial_delay" : 0.01,
    "max_delay"     : 30,
    "open_timeout"  : 5,
    "read_timeout"  : 300,
    "retry"         : null,
    "prefix"        : "",
    "denormalize"   : true,
    "status"        : true
}
}


cat handler.json
{
"handlers": {
"influxdb": {
   "type": "pipe",
    "command": "/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/metrics-influxdb.rb"    
}}}
```

**checks1,**

```
 {
  "checks": {
    "check_memory_linux": {
  "handlers": ["influxdb","default"],
  "command": "/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/check-memory-percent.rb -w 90 -c 95",
  "interval": 60,
  "occurrences": 5,
     "subscribers": [ "TEST" ]
  }}}
```

**checks2,**

```
{
"checks": {
"check_cpu_linux-elkctrl-pipe": {
  "type": "metric",
  "command": "/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/check-cpu.rb -w 80 -c 90",
  "subscribers": ["TEST"],
  "interval": 10,
  "handlers": ["debug","influxdb"]
}}}
```

Comment: What you mean by stuck? Is there an error? What are your handler configurations?

Comment: What are your check configurations?

Comment: Added. They look ok unless I need to use the "metrics-influxdb.rb" instead..

Answer (score 0):

To use InfluxDB to persist your data, you must have:

- [InfluxDB plugin installed](https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-influxdb) (also, installation and usage instructions here)
- Definitions for the plugin (an influxdb.json containin at least the host, port, user, password and database to be used by Sensu)

  - The definition, as other config files, must be in /etc/sensu/conf.d/
- Handler configuration set properly (also in conf.d)
- Mutator for InfluxDB (extensions)

Your checks must send results to the handler, so their definition must contain:

```
"handlers": [
        "influxdb"
      ]
```

Or whatever name you gave your handler.

Comment: I followed the link and configured accordingly but there are no entries in InfluxDB. I can manually add a metric to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Case, if the influxdb config you provided above is the full extent of your configuration, it would seem to be missing the username/password attributes required by the influxdb configuration. If they're present, but not provided in the post, no big deal. However, I'd recommend doing the following for your Sensu logs:

`grep -i influxdb /var/logs/sensu/sensu-server.log`

And seeing if the check result is getting sent to your influxdb instance. If they are, you should be receiving an error that might be pointing a bit more to what's going on.

You can also check your influxdb logs to see if they're getting a post from your Sensu server:

`journalctl -u influxdb.service -f`

But yeah, if the username/password is missing from the configuration, that'd be the first place that I start.